# how to decode following bytes in Python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x, unicode

in Python 3, used `socket.recv()` to get data from hardware, and get bytes: `b'\x00\x004\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00The Delta Wavelength (nm) is currently set to 0.008.\xfc\xa9\xf1\xd2Mb\x80?'`

how to decode the above to str(or unicode), `'\x00\x004\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00The Delta Wavelength (nm) is currently set to 0.008.\xfc\xa9\xf1\xd2Mb\x80?'`? tried 'ascii', 'latin-1', 'utf-8'. None works.

in Python 2.7,  `b'\x00\x004\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00The Delta Wavelength (nm) is currently set to 0.008.\xfc\xa9\xf1\xd2Mb\x80?'.decode('latin-1')` works, and get unicode `u'\x00\x004\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00The Delta Wavelength (nm) is currently set to 0.008.\xfc\xa9\xf1\xd2Mb\x80?'`. ascii, utf-8 not working either.

p.s. I am converting Python 2.7 code to Python 3.6

Comment: `b'\x00...'.decode('latin-1')` works for me and gives the desired output. Latin-1 always "works" for decoding a byte sequence, because all 256 possible states of a byte can be interpreted by Latin-1. In what way does it not work for you?

Comment: does it works in python 3.6? I got '\x00\x004\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00The Delta Wavelength (nm) is currently set to 0.008.ü©ñÒMb\x80?', all messed up after 0.008

Comment: No, that's the same. Check the output of `'\xfc\xa9\xf1\xd2Mb\x80?' == 'ü©ñÒMb\x80?'`

Comment: Thanks @lenz, why it shows so different?

Comment: You can insert any character with backslash notation, eg. `'\x41' == 'A'`. In the `repr()` form, non-printable characters (control characters and most whitespace) are shown with backslash escapes – just like you see `'\n'`, but the string contains an actual newline character, not "\" and "n". In Python 2, codepoints above 127 (like "ü") were treated like non-printables; this has been dropped in Python 3, that's the difference you see here.

Answer (score 1):

Wat information do you need? because if you only need the part:

```
The Delta Wavelength (nm) is currently set to 0.008.
```

Then you could just do something like:

```
data = socket.recv()[8:60].decode("utf-8")
```

or faster with memoryview

```
data = memoryview(socket.recv())[8:60].decode("utf-8")
```

I'm assuming you don't need the hardware's meta-data

Comment: the python 2.7 code separate the bytes to 3 parts: header('\x00\x004\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00'), message('The Delta Wavelength (nm) is currently set to 0.008.'), and content('\xfc\xa9\xf1\xd2Mb\x80?').

Comment: @Zheng then maybe you should also port that splitting part of the code to Python 3?

Comment: yes, then unpack('d', content)[0] to get the value and pass it on.