# Why '\xfc\xa9\xf1\xd2Mb\x80?' == 'ü©ñÒMb\x80?' is True in Python?

Tags: python, unicode

This was an comment from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502883/how-to-decode-following-bytes-in-python-3). but I was so confused, so ask it separatly.

in Python 3:

```
'\xfc\xa9\xf1\xd2Mb\x80?'=='ü©ñÒMb\x80?'
Out[42]: True
```

because the str in Python 3 is a sequence of unicode, I double checked them in Python 2.7 using

```
u'\xfc\xa9\xf1\xd2Mb\x80?' == u'ü©ñÒMb\x80?'
Out[29]: True
```

so these two unicode are the same, but why? they look very different.

Comment: `\x` are escape sequences for the actual characters shown on the RHS. They're the unicode values

Comment: to follow up @sshashank124, here is the unicode character for `\xfc` http://www.codetable.net/hex/fc --> maps to ü

Comment: `'\xfc'` Is how it is stored in memory. `ü` is how it is represented

Comment: backslash is the [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) in most languages including [python](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same because `'\xfc'` is another way of writing `ü`, and `'\xa9'` is another way to write `'©'`, and `print("\xfc") -> ü` and `print("\xa9")` -> `©`.

EDIT:

'\x...' means that this value is a unicode symbol, it's just a different way to show it.